# Token, tags, badges in input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Please see my last post for the answer.

On my website I have an input field. I want to use it that users on my page can "tag" other users to an image (similar to the "person xy is on this picture feature on facebook).
As soon as the person starts typing, I want to display possible values via jQuery autocomplete and as soon as the person selects one possible value, I'd like to have the selected value displayed in a tag. (I speak of the optical representation, for example that the value is underlined with a grey, rounded rectangle, like here on SO).

This is my input field:

```
        <label for="tokenfield">Wer ist auf diesem Bild zu sehen?</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tokenfield" value="example1, example2" />
```

Comment: Are you talking about the "placeholder" of the input, where it says Username?  You want to dynamically change that with jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked the question above a few weeks ago, but now realized, that it wasn't so well asked. And after a few days looking around, I found a solution for it.
I now wanted to let you know about my solution, just as a reference or hint for everyone else who finds this question or has the same problem.

So I am now using this library [GitHub Tokenfield](https://github.com/sliptree/bootstrap-tokenfield).

And use it like this:

```
        <label for="tokenfield">Wer ist auf diesem Bild zu sehen?</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tokenfield" value="red,green,blue" />
```

the basic JavaScript for initializing the input field is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#tokenfield').tokenfield();
})
```

However, if you want to use jQuery Autocomplete you can do so like this:

```
$('#tokenfield').tokenfield({
    autocomplete: {
        source: ['red','blue','green','yellow','violet','brown','purple','black','white']
    },
    showAutocompleteOnFocus: true,
    limit: 1
});
```

The input field gets initialized as tokenfield, so when entering data and pressing enter, it results in those token-badge-tag things.
After intitialization, it shows 3 tags, "red", "green" and "blue", which the library takes from the "value"-field of the input field.

I like this solution and library very much, because it also offers mechanisms to bind to jQuery Autocomplete via ajax, which is exactly what I wanted and needed.

I hope I was able to help somebody or save some time.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will change the placeholder as you type:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="Bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.placeholderValue').on("keyup", function () {
                $('.targetPlaceholder').attr('placeholder', $('.placeholderValue').val());
            })
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="placeholderValue form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control targetPlaceholder" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is not exactly what I looked for, but works well too ;)